# Measurablity of a Function on the Subsets of its Measurablity Set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider a measure space $(X, \Omega, \mu)$. Now if $f: E \mapsto [0, +\infty]$
 is measurable on $E\in \Omega$, what can be said about its measurability over $\hat E \subset E$, where $\hat E \in \Omega$?

My approach so far:

For starters, if $f$ is measurable on $E$, then $\forall c\in R$: $E_1=\{\forall x\in E, f(x)>c\}\in \Omega$.
Now, I have to check if an analogous $\hat E_1 \in \Omega$, where $\hat E_1=\{\forall x\in \hat E, f(x)>c\}$.  I can see that $\hat E_1 \subseteq E$ , but does this mean that $\hat E_1 \in \Omega$?

Any hints from this point onward? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\hat{E}_1 = \hat{E} \cap E_1$, and $\sigma$-algebras are closed under intersection.